# Is there any property of these matrix functions that might allow me to prove this?

Tags: matrices, vector-space-isomorphism

We can prove by definition of transposition and inversion that for an inversible matrix A, $(A^T)^-1 = (A^{-1})^T$

I would like to see through other means when this can happen (for other matrix functions)

In this case, for example, let's define a Subspace of $R^{n \times n}$ and two functions:

$ S = {A \in R^{n \times n} / \exists A^{-1}} $

$f:S \rightarrow S$, $f(A) = A^T$

$g:S \rightarrow S$, $g(A) = A^{-1}$

These functions are not just isomorphisms but are also their own inverse.

Is this enough to state (fog)(A) = (gof)(A)?

If this is the case, how do we call an isomorphism that is its own inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Being an isomorphism that is its own inverse is not sufficient. Let me define on $2\times2$ matrices such an isomorphism  $\phi$ which simply changes the sign of  the $(1,2)$  entry.

Now  $\phi(A)^{-1}$ and $\phi(A^{-1})$ are different

Comment: So is there any other property about these isomoprhisms in particular that lets us state that thr order in which they are executed is irrelevant?

Comment: The computational formula for inverse involves calculating the determinant of the given matrix  (and its minors, which are again determinants).  Now the property $\det(A) =\det(A^T)$ leads to  $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$.